# Jquery Ajax selectors

Tags: php, html, jquery, post

Im trying to make something like this http://demos.99points.info/facebook_wallpost_system/ which is a comment system.  I have the ajax code below except i don't know how to uniqely select textareas.  The challenge is that the number of posts is variable so all of the posts need to be uniquely identified so that when the data is put into the database i know which post it relates to.

JQUERY:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('document').ready(function(){

$('.commentContainer').load('../writecomment.php');
        //commentContainer is a class so it applies to all of the textareas, but i need this selector to be unique

$('.submitCommentBox').click(function(){

            //these are the selectors that i can't get to work right
    var comment = $('').val();
    var postid = $('').val();


    $.post('../comment.php',
    {

    comment: comment,
    postid: postid,



    },
    function(response){

        $('#commentContainer').load('../writecomment.php');
        $('.commentBox').val('');

    }

    }

    return false;

}):

});

</script>
```

HTML/PHP

```
<?php while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

echo"
<p name='singlePost'>$post[$f]</p>
<div id='commentContainer'></div>
<textarea class='commentBox'></textarea>
<input type='button' value='submit' class='submitCommentBox'>";
 }
```

basically the HTML/PHP generates for each post on the page as to create a textarea and subimt button for each post.  therefore the user can comment on each post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the markup in the link you provided, I would do something like:

```
var container  = $(this).closest('.friends_area');

var comment    = $(container).find('.commentbox').val();
var questionid = $(container).find('#hidden').val();
var answerid   = $(container).find('').val();
```

---

A more correct solution would be something like:

#### HTML

```
<div id="posting">
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="hidden" name="record_id" value="123" />
        <textarea name="comment"></textarea>
        <button type="submit">Comment</button>
    </form>

    ...
</div>
```

#### JS

```
$('#posting').on('submit', 'form', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this).closest('form');

    $.post($(form).attr('action'), $(form).serialize(), function() {
        $('#commentContainer').load('../writecomment.php');
        $('.commentBox').val('');
    });
});
```

Comment: nice solution but i was just wondering why you gave the hidden input a value of "123" and why did you take the action attribute of the form in the $.post?

Comment: [Graceful degradation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement). An oversimplified explenation: if a use doesn't have JS enabled, the form will still submit to the appropriate script with the appropriate data. It won't be as sexy, but it will still work.

Comment: so should i fill in the action with the current page? and why is the hidden value 123?

Comment: The code I provided is just an example. Customize it to suit your needs. In your case, the `action` should be "'../comment.php'". `123` is just a placeholder... again, in your case, it should be whatever your `postid` is.

Comment: also your JS is missing the comment.php which inserts the variables into the database.  shouldnt comment.php be in the place of the $(fiorm).attr('action')?

Comment: my bad.  i should have said that the current page is index.php.  comment.php is the mysql insert function

Comment: No. "**../comment.php**" should be the `action` attribute of the form. That's what `$(form).attr('action')` is looking for. Technically what you suggested *would* work, but I'd avoid hard-coding the URL into your JS.

Comment: ah! very creative solution. however,  when i tried to insert a comment, the comment was put into the database but the page redirected to "http://localhost/comment.php" which was blank as there is no html on comment.php

Comment: am i missing a "return false;" or something because i need to stop the code from submitting the form

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6279/discussion-between-ayman-safadi-and-user802370)